# Am I breaking some Onion Architecture rule?

Tags: architecture, .net, enterprise-architecture, onion-architecture

Based on the project structure below i will have some questions

- Domain Layer

1) **MyApp.Domain.Entities (DLL)**

Product.cs

PagedResult.cs

***Referentes***

No References

2) **MyApp.Domain.Interfaces (DLL)**

IUnitOfWork.cs

IProductRepository.cs

***Referentes***

MyApp.Domain.Entities

3) **MyApp.Domain.Common.Interfaces (DLL)**

IClock.cs

ICryptography.cs

ILogging.cs

***Referentes***

No References

- Infrastructure Layer

1) **MyApp.Infrastructure.Logging**

Will implement the interface ILogging

***Referentes***

MyApp.Domain.Common.Interfaces

2) **MyApp.Infrastructure.Cryptography**

Will implement the interface ICryptography

***Referentes***

MyApp.Domain.Common.Interfaces

4) **MyApp.Infrastructure.Data**

Will implement the interface **IUnitOfWork.cs** e **IProductRepository.cs**

***Referentes***

MyApp.Domain.Entities

MyApp.Domain.Interfaces

------------------------------ Questions ---------------------------------

A) In my ***Domain Layer*** I have ***MyApp.Domain.Common.Interfaces*** that will keep interfaces that can be used for all project, this interfaces will represent common elements that whole project can use and will be implemented at Infrastructure Layer.

Am I breaking some Onion Architecture rule having it in my Domain Layer?

Comment: Common libraries live outside of the domain of the onion architecture, and are treated the same way as they are in any other application.  The trick is to respect the boundaries of each layer and their purpose.  See [here](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) for advice on how to manage the layer boundaries.

Comment: See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/360850

Comment: Robert Harvey, After reading the links you sent i think i'm at the correct way! Thank you so much for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my app and from my investigation, it seems that most people think that this is a bad idea:

1. When Entities make use of Repositories, ie: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694241/ddd-the-rule-that-entities-cant-access-repositories-directly)
2. When Entities make use of Services, this could be avoided by simple refactors, ie: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380882/ddd-entities-making-use-of-services)

In your case, it seems that the IClock and ICryptography is part of the delivery mechanism, not a domain and therefore they should live in the infrastructure layer. It is not clear why your Entities should depend on these. If they do not depend on that infrastructure then you shouldn't keep it in the Domain layer even if this is a common code for all project.

As for ILogging you can solve it by logging domain events produced by your Entities. This way the logging can be a part of a Repository that lives in the infrastructure layer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729371/where-does-a-logger-goes-in-ddd) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882509/ddd-domain-model-and-logging)

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention grzegorz.kosciolek, 

I read the links you sent, below i highlight some points that can clarify doubts

1) I`m not working with DDD, what my MyApp.Domain.Entities has are several POCO entities 
that i got from Reverse Engineer Code first because i`m creating a new system based on a 
database created 15 years ago

Comment: 2) In MyApp.Domain.Common.Interfaces I have the interfaces below

A) "ICryptography" is extremmely important to my application, but after rethinking some points 
I only use "ICryptography" when i compose some objects at User Interface before sending them to my 
Service Layer. 

It will contain several methods thare are responsible for encrypt and decrypt information used for
some specific entities and is extremely important

Comment: B) "IClock" was removed from several places of my application and I concentrated everything in my context
before saving, like shown in detail below

It will contain a method that will return the current time based on some local time rules, 
and several entities of my domain use it, but after a refactory i only use it in my context like 
i show below

Comment: public override int SaveChanges() {

  IClock i_Clock = new Clock();

   foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("RegisterDate") != null)){
      if (entry.State == EntityState.Added){
        entry.Property("RegisterDate").CurrentValue = i_Clock.CurrentTime();
      }

      if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified){
        entry.Property("RegisterDate").IsModified = false;
      }
 }
}

Comment: C) "IValidation" i use only to verify User Input in my User Interface, but is also extremmely important to my app, 
because without it, my application will save invalid information

I Kept the interfaces above in my MyApp.Domain.Common.Interfaces because they are extremely important to my Business, even if they are not used in all layers

Comment: 3) In MyApp.Infrastructure.Utility I have interfaces and concrete implementations of them
A) "IFileManagement": Saves and retrives files stored at disk associated with some entities. I only use it at User
 Interface because when i compose some objects i only send them to my service layer with the location of the file at disk
B) "IEmailManagement": Send Emails in case of Server errors, only used at User Interface
C) "ILogging": Log actions, only used at User Interface when data is committed

Comment: 4) In MyApp.Infrastructure.Common I have the concrete implementations of MyApp.Domain.Common.Interfaces

Comment: -> Summing up: **Domain Layer** _MyApp.Domain.Common.Interfaces (DLL)_ ICryptography; IClock; IValidation **Infrastructure Layer** _MyApp.Infrastructure.Common (DLL)_ Cryptography: ICryptography Clock: IClock; Validation: IValidation; _MyApp.Infrastructure.Utility (DLL)_ FileManagement: IFileManagement; EmailManagement : IEmailManagement; Logging: ILogging;

Comment: Any criticism or suggestion will be very welcome and respected